# How to implement token authorization using Ruby Rspec Please?

Tags: ruby, rspec, automated-tests

Friends, in my project below how do I get the authentication that is generated in the swagger apis?
If I have an api in swagger with the post method where I pass the username and password to generate this authentication and from the generated key I pass it as an argument in the api.
how I create this architecture. In my tests directory I have the apis, as you usually do?

```
require 'httparty'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
  config.color_mode = true

  config.before(:all) do
    class HttParty
      include HTTParty
      base_uri   'https://testtesttestxxxxx/'
      
  end
end
end

require 'httparty'

RSpec.describe 'Validar a api de usuários' do

  it 'Deve retornar 200 para API Fichas - Corporativo' do
    response = HttParty.get('/index.html')
    expect(response.code).to eql(200)
    p response.code
  end
  
  it 'O retorno não deve ser vazio' do
    response = HttParty.get('/index.html')
    expect(response.parsed_response).not_to be_empty
  end
end
```

Comment: Use a before block, or a shared example that created your token before each context. Otherwise, grab your token before running your specs, and simply refer to the appropriate environment variable when passing tokens.

Comment: First of all thank you. Do you have a example Todd?